# ActiveJob's default behavior when an exception is raised during execution

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activejob

I am confused about how `ActiveJob` handles retries when there is an exception raised during the execution of a job. The [Rails Guide about `ActiveJob`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html#retrying-or-discarding-failed-jobs) has this example:

> 10.1 Retrying or Discarding failed jobs
>
> It's also possible to retry or discard a job if an exception is raised during execution. For example:
>
> ```
> class RemoteServiceJob < ApplicationJob
>   retry_on CustomAppException # defaults to 3s wait, 5 attempts
>
>   discard_on ActiveJob::DeserializationError
>
>   def perform(*args)
>     # Might raise CustomAppException or ActiveJob::DeserializationError
>   end
> end
> ```
>
> To get more details see the API Documentation for [`ActiveJob::Exceptions`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveJob/Exceptions/ClassMethods.html).

That means there is a method to explicitly tell `ActiveJob` to retry a job on certain exceptions and at the same time, there is a method to explicitly tell `ActiveJob` to discard a job on certain exceptions.

But how does `ActiveJob` handle exceptions when the developer didn't define `retry_on` or `discard_on`? What is the default behavior? Would it discard the job? Would it retry the job? And if, how often and in what interval?

Comment: How the jobs are actually executed depends on the adapter used. You can find the implementation for the inline adapter in [ActiveJob::Execution](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/fbe2433be6e052a1acac63c7faf287c52ed3c5ba/activejob/lib/active_job/execution.rb). As far as I can tell it does not have a default list of exceptions that it handles.

Comment: The [default async adapter](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/fbe2433be6e052a1acac63c7faf287c52ed3c5ba/activejob/lib/active_job/queue_adapters/async_adapter.rb) relies pretty heavily on the [concurrent-ruby gem](https://github.com/ruby-concurrency/concurrent-ruby) for execution. See the docs for [Concurrent::ScheduledTask#execute](http://ruby-concurrency.github.io/concurrent-ruby/master/Concurrent/ScheduledTask.html#execute-class_method).

Comment: @max So you are saying that the default behavior for retry failed active jobs entirely depends on the used backend? That means with one backend (for example Sidekiq) the default might be to retry multiple time over a period of several days whereas when switching to another backend the default might be discard job on failure?

Comment: Yes, that's my understanding.